# Why I can't increment the chronometer value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, increment

I would like a time counter and I found the next code. The problem is when I change `time = new Date(time - 1000);` to `time = new Date(time + 1000);`

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        a{
        margin: 0 10px;
        color: gray;
        }
        .time{
            font-size: 50px;
            margin: 20px;
            font-family: monospace;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var startValue = 1000; //Number of milliseconds
        var time = new Date(startValue);
        var interv;
        $(function(){
            displayTime();
            $(".start").on("click", function(){
            interv = setInterval(function(){
                //time = new Date(time - 1000);
                time = new Date(time + 1000);
                displayTime();
            }, 1000);
            });
            $(".stop").on("click", function(){
                clearInterval(interv);
                time = new Date(startValue);
                displayTime();
            });
            $(".pause").on("click", function(){
                clearInterval(interv);
            });
            $(".reset").on("click", function(){
                time = new Date(startValue);
                displayTime();
            });
        });

        function displayTime(){
            $(".time").text(fillZeroes(time.getMinutes()) + ":" + fillZeroes(time.getSeconds()));
        }

        function fillZeroes(t){
            t += "";
            return t.length==1? "0" + t : t;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="start">start</a>
<a href="#" class="stop">stop</a>
<a href="#" class="pause">pause</a>
<a href="#" class="reset">reset</a>
<div class="time"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can increment the time?
Thank you!

Comment: I discovered the next absurd solution: time = new Date(time - -1000);

Comment: Yeap, it's all about implicit type conversion. Welcome to JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to get a timestamp from a Date object. In your case:

```
time = new Date(time.getTime() + 1000);
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/G8yo5l4wHe2yv9S3fjLI?p=preview

Comment: @JuanCamacho Do you wonder why `-` works while `+` doesn't? I can add a bit of explanation if you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution  https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/eag01ojj/

```
$(".start").on("click", function(){
            interv = setInterval(function(){                
                                time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 1);
                displayTime();
            }, 1000);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you try to instanciate a Date object with another Date object as argument.

```
var time = new Date(startValue);
...
time = new Date(time + 1000);
```

Try to use console.log() next time for debug.

You also have a few other problems, like why do you start your counter at 1 instead of zero ?

Here is a quick working example that should fix everything: https://jsfiddle.net/r6k06w40/3/